# HTML/CSS - Slideshow nav button disappeared

Tags: html, css, button, slideshow, nav

I have been making a website for my private business. Been loving making the website. Back to topic..

Yesterday I was having an issue with my menu button not working with my slideshow. After doing a lot of research online I found out that I had an issue with my two jQuery plugins that I fixed. Everything was smooth and it look amazing! And than this day comes and ruins it all. Now all of a sudden the arrowkeys

[image]

This might be a stupid question but can code change in one day? Or is this a human error. I actually haven't touched the computer at all today before now.

Im so confused.

Comment: Hard to say why without seeing an example with codes

Comment: When working with CSS styling make sure you're clearing your browser cache, sometimes the browser will save CSS settings and won't update till cache is cleared. I use a chrome extension called cache killer.

Answer (score 0):

No code doesn't change in a day if it's untouched.  Likely something that happened is that your browser had been saving cookies keeping CSS a certain way then finally the cache cleared and the CSS updated.  That's my guess, post code or we can't help you further.